# How to pass string argument to javascript method

Tags: javascript, objective-c

How to pass string argument to javascript method

my code

```
function paginatePage(getPath) {


    alert("from pagenate page");
    alert("home path initial " + getPath);
}
```

unable to get the alert message

when i called the method

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paginatePage(%s)",getPath]
```

Comment: What are you passing through?

Comment: code seems correct. what are you trying to pass?

Comment: There's obviously something extremely important you're not telling us here.  From what context are you attempting to call this method?  What programming environment are we talking about here?

Comment: So we have JavaScript and Objective-C here. What is their connection? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Probably just the quotes around the string literal missing?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paginatePage('%s')",getPath]
```

Answer (score 1):

You possibly need to qualify the string with quotes.

I don't know what that NSString syntax is, but something like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paginatePage('%s')",getPath]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error does not come from this, because the code is 100% valid : this is how you pass a string argument to a function.

If you could provide some more code, maybe we could help you.

Also, make sure no other function has the same name, or maybe it's how you called the function?